# Flutter vertical scrollable listView in vertical scrollable pageView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Looking for help on this one, it seemed simple to at first but couldn't figure it out...

Basically I'm trying to make a page with a vertical scrollable listView inside a vertical scrollable pageView. For example the list is on page 2, the user is on page one and scrolls down to page 2. Now he scrolls down until the end of the list and I want his to be able to scroll a bit more that it would go to page 3.

Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Comment: Shouldn't `Column` be a better widget than `ListView` for your case?

Comment: ok, i can use a `Column`, but it needs to be scrollable so i'll wrap it with a `SingleChildScrollView` and now we have the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

What works for me is that we need to attach the ListView's scroll controller to listen to the scroll position. The page controller will then move to either next or previous page.

```
PageController pageController;
ScrollController scrollController;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  pageController = PageController();
  scrollController = ScrollController();

  scrollController.addListener(() {
    // listView reaches the bottom
    if (scrollController.offset >= scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - 100 &&
      !scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      pageController.nextPage(duration: const Duration(seconds: 1), curve: ElasticOutCurve());
    }

    // listView reaches the top
    if (scrollController.offset <= scrollController.position.minScrollExtent &&
        !scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      pageController.previousPage(duration: const Duration(seconds:1), curve: ElasticOutCurve());
    }
  });
}
```

Don't forget to attach the controllers

```
PageView(
  controller: pageController,
  ...


ListView(
  controller: scrollController,
  ...
```

Comment: wow, cool. neat solution. i see though that the user cant 'hover' between pages,in other words the scrolling acts like a button (and the user doesn't get a 'true' scrolling experience). is that possible or it's asking too much from flutter?

Comment: I can't think of anything on top of my head, but from my perspective, it's not ideal to have multiple scroll controllers pointing to the same axis. So maybe you could wrap everything into a list and apply some calculations to make each part of the page sticky.

Answer (score 1):

This GitHub [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50946) has a handy solution that I think has the "hover" behavior between each page that you need. Here is the sample code provided within the thread:

```
void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Example()
      )
    );
  }

}

class Example extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();

}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {

  PageController _pageController;
  ScrollController _listScrollController;
  ScrollController _activeScrollController;
  Drag _drag;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
    _listScrollController = ScrollController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    _listScrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _handleDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    if (_listScrollController.hasClients && _listScrollController.position.context.storageContext != null) {
      final RenderBox renderBox = _listScrollController.position.context.storageContext.findRenderObject();
      if (renderBox.paintBounds.shift(renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero)).contains(details.globalPosition)) {
        _activeScrollController = _listScrollController;
        _drag = _activeScrollController.position.drag(details, _disposeDrag);
        return;
      }
    }
    _activeScrollController = _pageController;
    _drag = _pageController.position.drag(details, _disposeDrag);
  }

  void _handleDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    if (_activeScrollController == _listScrollController && details.primaryDelta < 0 && _activeScrollController.position.pixels == _activeScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      _activeScrollController = _pageController;
      _drag?.cancel();
      _drag = _pageController.position.drag(
        DragStartDetails(
          globalPosition: details.globalPosition,
          localPosition: details.localPosition
        ),
        _disposeDrag
      );
    }
    _drag?.update(details);
  }

  void _handleDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    _drag?.end(details);
  }

  void _handleDragCancel() {
    _drag?.cancel();
  }

  void _disposeDrag() {
    _drag = null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawGestureDetector(
      gestures: <Type, GestureRecognizerFactory>{
          VerticalDragGestureRecognizer: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
          () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer(),
          (VerticalDragGestureRecognizer instance) {
            instance
              ..onStart = _handleDragStart
              ..onUpdate = _handleDragUpdate
              ..onEnd = _handleDragEnd
              ..onCancel = _handleDragCancel;
          }
          )
      },
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      child: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          ListView(
            controller: _listScrollController,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: List.generate(
              25,
              (int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text('Item $index')
                );
              }
            )
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text('Page 2')
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }

}
```